# Generate a liste containing all the instances of a variable

Tags: prolog

i am trying to generate a list in Prolog that contains all the instances of a variable.
for exemple:

```
entree( 'foie gras' ).
entree( 'salade gourmande' ).
entree( 'crudites' ).

generateliste(E,L)//L should be L=["foie gras','salade gourmande,'crudites']
```

I tried this:

```
generateliste(E,[E|R]):-entree(E),not(member(E,R)),generateliste(E,R).
```

but i know it won't work because there is no base case to stop the recursion ,
can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can use e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the missing base case, you have a more fundamental problem.

`not(member(E,R))` will never succeed, regardless the actual value of `E`, if `R` is a variable.
Then you have to 'reverse the information flow', and keep a temporary list (called `Acc` here) to check for already collected items:

```
generateliste(Acc,[E|R]) :-
    entree(E),
    not(member(E,Acc)),
    generateliste([E|Acc],R).
generateliste(_,[]).
```

Call it in this way

```
?- generateliste([],L).
L = ['foie gras', 'salade gourmande', crudites] .
```

but remember the savy hint you got from Peter and brebs: you should study the library [findall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3, [setof](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)/3 and [bagof](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)/3 builtins.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions

setof/3, bagof/3, findall/3 (findall has some subtle nonlogical problems)